# creating a list which works as inparameter for gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a school development project and I'm quite new to development. I have been reading online but can't find the answer I'm looking for.

So far I have created a listbox in my Windows Forms application which I want to select all the values from one of my columns, and these should work as a inparameter to display data in my dataGridView based on the parameter.

I have created 70% of my project and this functionality is what is left. My database is in Azure and I can write to it and add new rows, but I can't read anything to my application when I run it.

code for listview, at first I just want to be able to select. Later on somehow write the choosen parameter to a variable that I can use as a condition in my dataGridView.

This is the code for my gridview so far I just want to display all data in it, but it's not showing anything.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
public partial class CompanyForm : Form
{
    public CompanyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Connection String
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].
    ConnectionString;
    private void createCompany_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBoxCompanyName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill information");
            return;
        }
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            //Create SqlConnection
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            (
            "insert into dbo.Company  (companyName) 
            values(@companyName)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue
           (
            "@companyName",   
            textBoxCompanyName.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapt.Fill(ds);
            MessageBox.Show("GJ");

        }
    }

    // The code that is not filling my datagrid
    private void dataEmployees_Load()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            (
                "Select fname,ename FROM dbo.Users", con
            );
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataEmployees.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My connection string is working it's already being able to insert data to the tables that I have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem why you Grid isn't shown any data is that you try to bind a SqlDataReader to it. This isn't working, because the Grid doesn't support this as DataSource.

What you need as DataSource is `DataTable, IList<T>, IBindingList<T>`. In your case the DataTable would be the easiest solution. Try this out:

```
protected void DataEmployees()
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
  {
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
     (
       "Select firstname,lastname FROM employees",con
      );
      SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Load(dr);
      dataEmployees.DataSource = dt;
   }
 }
```

Notice that Methods are written Uppercase in C#. Further notice that you don't need to close the connection manually if you use a using-block. On the end of the using-block it's automatically closed/disposed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunatly it's still not working. I don't know why, my datagrid is just empty.

Comment: @StephenSmith Please set a breakpoint after dt.Load(dr); and check if there are some entries.

Comment: The code never runs to the breakpoint it seems like that is the problem :/

Comment: @Stephen Smith Then you never call the Method DataEmployees or you catch an Exception and do nothing in this case and your sql isn't correct.

Comment: Yes it seems that is the problem, dont know why it's not being called. I have updated my code above. I'm using another SQL insert for another table at first and the connection string variable is accessible in this form